# What does phrase 死牢 refer to?

Tags: vocabulary

Does it means a prison that people is left for dead? Or does it means a prison to imprison a death-sentence criminal?

Comment: bkrs：死牢 关押死囚的监牢。 [death cell; condemned cell] 关押死囚的牢房 death-row cell 1) 为宴飨而宰杀的牲畜。对生牢而言。 2) 关押死囚的牢狱。 4 sample sentences at jukuu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

死牢 is a place for death sentence prisoner